# Configuring maven with EJB and JSF: Critical error during deployment

Tags: maven, jsf-2, glassfish, ejb

I have been migrating an ear project from Ant to Maven and I found with this problem:

**GRAVE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! The default implementation must override this method**

The POM configuration from project web is the next:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alquilaweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>Maven-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I googled a lot, but I could not find any solution. Maybe it is an stupid thing, but I can´t  find where happens this exception.

Regards,

Sarang

Comment: I'm no Maven guy, but why don't you have your `javax.servlet` entries set to `provided` or `compile`? Those pieces are already provided by Glassfish itself and even more, the Servlet version is conflicting. Java EE 6 / Glassfish 3 is Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Ahhh It can be that. When I come back to home I will set the scope for this dependency. @BalusC I have a question: What happens if I add javax dependency and not javax.servlet? is it going to work, right? Because javax contains the servlet api? or it is neccesary to include explicitly the javax.servlet? thanks man!

Comment: I don't do Maven. I was merely reasoning based on logically thinking.

Comment: Ok. It wasn't that. I received too this log.. java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! The default implementation must override this method

Comment: I have changed the configuration of pom file and I just let this for jsf .. <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency> .. But, I get the same error. Please, Help me!!!! I found that this error appears when there is a conflict with the jsf library or something is wrong setting.

Comment: @BalusC off topic but what do use instead? I find maven pretty nice but your opinions and practice has been very valuable before

Comment: @Karl: Maven is on paper nice and I believe that it is useful for a lot of developers, but in practice (in both real world and hobby projects) there just wasn't a *need* for it. We're happy controlling/managing the dependencies ourselves.

Comment: I think that, which was the error. It was it was not necessary to specify the scope of jsf, but for the jstl and servlet-api yes. In this case is provided. The artifact jsf is not inside the ejb package.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. Then I updated my JDK Compiler version to 1.8 and it worked for me.